# can't use override func prepareForSegue ( >>Cell Title to navigation item<< )

Tags: swift, segue

I have a problem in prepare For Segue When I try to add Cell Title to navigation item This problem appears

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvali.png)

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("indeaa", sender: tableView)
    return indexPath
}


  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    if segue.identifier == "indeaa"
    {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
         let indexpath:NSIndexPath = tableaa.indexPathForSelectedRow!
              vc.title = arr[indexpath.row]
    } 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for app crashing is that the optional variable is not being unwrapped appropriately.
You can unwrap the optional using optional binding or chaining method.

Replace -

```
let indexpath:NSIndexPath = tableaa.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

with

```
if let indexpath = tableaa.indexPathForSelectedRow! {vc.title = arr[indexpath.row]}
```

Comment: The problem is resolved, but appeared another problem

Comment: When i click on cell 1 shows the first Navigation bar is empty and when i return and  click on anther ( cell ) 
i show cell 1 name and When i click on any cell i show name of 
( anther ( cell ) )